# MySql memory allocation

Tags: mysql

Anybody knows how MySql allocates memory for "text" and "blob" in case i'm inserting smaller data than the max size of the column ?

For example, What happens when i insert 50K string into a "text" column? Is the entire 65K column allocated ?